# How do I join rows from the same table with slightly different info?

Tags: mysql, self-join

We have a new sector of our company that is being put into our employee record feed.   However this sector is listed as contractors as there are still parts of the sector that need access to systems that require domain access...    so...

I have:

TABLE EMP

EmpID,
email,
INFO1,
INFO2,
INF03...

and for Tom Smith
5763,
tom.smith@co1.com,
blah blah,
blah blah,
blah blah...

and also for Tom Smith
ZZ98401,
tom.smith@co2.com,
null,
null,
null...

Not everyone on the feed is like this, only about 10%.   Most are in case number 2.

What I am looking for is the easiest way to equate the two rows associated with Tom and fill in as much info on Tom as I can because some fields come from one account and other fields come from the other.   The only thing that can accurately make the two rows common is the beginning of the email address - this is standardized.   So there should be a few thousand people (rows of duplicates) on my feed that I can combine if it can be done right.

I would also like to capture both EmpIDs somehow in the same row and both email addresses.

Comment: Read about "self JOIN".

Comment: @RickJames - I did and kept getting blank queries.   I would have shown examples but I had about 15 tries and nothing.

Comment: Let's see one of your attempts; maybe we can improve on it.